# Cisco Router ro Router IPSEC config

Tags: cisco, ipsec

I have the following configurations,

R1:

```
crypto keyring KR
  pre-shared-key address 1.1.1.2 key cisco
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp profile PROFILE
   keyring KR
   match identity address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.255
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANSFORM_SET esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 1.1.1.2
 set transform-set TRANSFORM_SET
 set isakmp-profile PROFILE
 match address IPSEC_ACL
!    
ip access-list extended IPSEC_ACL
 permit ip host 1.1.1.1 host 1.1.1.2
!
int e0/0
ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
crypto map MAP
```

and R2:

```
crypto keyring KR
  pre-shared-key address 1.1.1.1 key cisco
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp profile PROFILE
   keyring KR
   match identity address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANSFORM_SET esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 1.1.1.1
 set transform-set TRANSFORM_SET
 set isakmp-profile PROFILE
 match address IPSEC_ACL
!    
ip access-list extended IPSEC_ACL
 permit ip host 1.1.1.2 host 1.1.1.1
!
int e0/0
ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
crypto map MAP
```

The IPSEC tunnel won't come up any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The match address ACL should be the IP ranges which will be going over the link not the IPs where the crypto maps are.

For example, If IP range 192.168.1.0/24 is on R1 and 192.168.2.0/24 is on R2 and the hosts on 192.168.1.0/24 want to talk to 192.168.2.0/24 via the tunnel you would need to set the ACLs to be the following.

R1

```
ip access-list extended IPSEC_ACL
 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
```

R2

```
ip access-list extended IPSEC_ACL
 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

The routers will then try to bring up the tunnel when traffic goes from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.2.0/24 or from 192.168.2.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24

You can try the following to look at the debug output to see where the tunnel is failing on coming up

```
debug crypto isakmp
debug crypto ipsec
```

to disable the debugging use

```
undebug all
```

or

```
no debug all
```

if you don't see any debug output you might need to enable terminal monitor

```
terminal monitor
```